# Video encoder with low CPU usage on Atom 230

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, video-encoding, video-codecs, intel-atom

What are my options for screen capturing on Atom 230 CPU that will result in reasonably low CPU usage?
I'm using ffmpeg and would like to leave CPU power to other applications while recording a screencast without lags.
Maybe there's hardware support for certain codec?